# SPFx and WebPart - failure : Not deployed on my site, not added in site content but still usable?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, solution-deployment, deploy

We have programmed a Survey WebPart for a customer.

But, drum rolls please, .... it does not work as it is expected to.

**Let me explain :**

We created the customerWebparts.sppkg with Visual Studio Code. Inside, we have a bunch of WPs including the Survey WP.
In the Appcatalog, the customerWebparts.sppkg is deployed. It is not deployed for all tenant.(because we wanted to add it on certain sites only).

In a communication site that we have manually created on the tenant, in Site Contents, we have no trace of our customerWebparts App. (nor the list used for the Survey WP, because we manually add it)
So far so good, everything is working fine.

Except... when we go on a Site Page, the Survey WP is available to add to the page. (on the top of that, because we did not create the right list -because we do not want to have Surveys on that site!- the webpart is not working fine -which is normal but frustrating).

SO where can this come from ? Even in our code, i can't say we did something special for it.

Thanks for your lights !

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed the SPFx solution as Tenant-scoped, you could add the webpart to all site collections(you won't see the solution in site contents).

Check Official guideline [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/tenant-scoped-deployment).

[image]